# Capture the API Request after clicking a button

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, automated-tests

Scenario:
We have an application which generates reports based on the given filters (checkbox, radio-buttons, dropdowns, textbox)from the form. Once a user clicks on "generate report" button an API [Request Header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FldKX.png) request gets called and a pdf/csv reports gets downloaded.

I can see this requests in browser Network tab under

Headers[tab] -> Request Headers
- :path api/path/to/download/pdf

Headers[tab] -> Request URL: full/api/path/url/to/download/pdf

Can we capture this request URLs using JavaScript/Java?

Comment: Can you provide an extract of your backend code? If you want to log requests, that's where you need to act. Anything you do js side, can be easily manipulated.

Comment: yes, just make the get/post using javascript and you can retrieve the headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a proxy to capture the webrequests.
Browsermob proxy is a popular with selenium.
See this example from https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/browsermob-proxy-selenium-example:

```
   // start the proxy
    proxy = new BrowserMobProxyServer();
    proxy.start(0);

    //get the Selenium proxy object - org.openqa.selenium.Proxy;
    Proxy seleniumProxy = ClientUtil.createSeleniumProxy(proxy);

    // configure it as a desired capability
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, seleniumProxy);
    
    //set chromedriver system property
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath+"chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    
    // enable more detailed HAR capture, if desired (see CaptureType for the complete list)
    proxy.enableHarCaptureTypes(CaptureType.REQUEST_CONTENT, CaptureType.RESPONSE_CONTENT);

    // create a new HAR with the label "seleniumeasy.com"
    proxy.newHar("seleniumeasy.com");

    // open seleniumeasy.com
    driver.get("https://seleniumeasy.com/");
```